# How do I bring my 3D model to the front like a button to press?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I managed to create a 3D model and would like to put it on my website as a button people can click on before enterting into the main page to see the portfolio.

The only problem is, I managed to get the 3D model on the website but it's behind a video and I would like to bring it to the middle like this: [image]

Instead of the middle button, it would just be the character I made on Blender and people can click on it or rotate it.

Here is the current code if anyone wouldn't mind helping me solve this last step <3:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maxiumum-scale=5.0">

<link rel="icon" href="ghost.ico">

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137617043-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-137617043-2');



<!-- 3D  REQUIRED: Web Components polyfill to support Edge and Firefox < 63 -->

src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.1.3/webcomponents-loader.js">
src;"https://unpkg.com/intersection-observer@0.5.1/intersection-observer.js">
src;"https://unpkg.com/resize-observer-polyfill@1.5.0/dist/ResizeObserver.js">
src;"https://unpkg.com/focus-visible@5.0.2/dist/focus-visible.js">

</script> 

<model-viewer src="gnome.glb" alt="my 3D Gnome Model made from Blender for www.GhostRobles.com" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls auto-rotate ar></model-viewer>

<!-- Loads <model-viewer> for modern browsers: -->
    <script type="module"
    src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Loads <model-viewer> for old browsers like IE11: -->
    <script nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js">
    </script>

<!--- 3d CONTENT END --->

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137617043-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer ; window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-137617043-2');</script>
  
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PTZXGBD');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<!--- Google Tag Manager -->

</head>

<main>
<body>

    <title> HQ </title>
    
    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="video-container thick-border">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline
            class="video-background">
            <source src="coiblue.m4v" type="video/mp4" alt="Gx0st"></video>
        </div>
        <div class="model-viewer">
             <a href="home.html" class="btn">
            <img width=2732 height=2048 class="module" src="gnome.glb" alt="GhostRobles Portfolio @GhostRobles">
        </a>
            </div>      
    </section>

    <!-- Lets get mobile viewport -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly"/>
<meta id="viewport-tag" name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover"/>

</main>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PTZXGBD"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> 

<style> 

.thick-border {
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: double;
  }


.smaller-image {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
}
    

@font-face 
{font-family: 'vcr_osd_mono-webfont'; 
src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot'); 
src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('webfont.svg#svgFontname') format('svg');} * {
font-display: swap;
}


    :root {
    --primary-color: #000000;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "vcr_osd_mono-webfont";
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/toons/too-3/too297.cur), auto;
}


a {
  font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(255, 0, 0);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.showcase {
    height: 100vh; /* changes image top to bottom */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
     /* this used to be here: background: var(--primary-color) url('coiblue.m4v') no-repeat center
        center/contain; /*   /* changed from cover to contain */ }

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    object-fit: contain;
}

.video-container:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: static;
}

.content {
    z-index: 2;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 2px 1px 2px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 30%;
    border: solid rgb(255, 0, 0) 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -450px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); /* this changes the button hover */
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0; /* fixed, note, don't add another repository. */
}

*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
model-viewer{
width:100%;
height:600px;;
background-color:transparent;
}

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to play around with the code and see how I can do it in the meantime.....